# I could not solve the EmptyProjectionMember error in EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table on access. The structure of this table is as follows. In this table, I record access information of 2 types of people. The GC field indicates whether the access is entry or exit. I am trying to get the number of people whose last movement is inside according to the type of person.

But I get an error:

> The given key 'EmptyProjectionMember' was not present in the dictionary

I kindly ask for your support on the subject.

`AccessData` model:

```
public required string DeviceName { get; set; }
public required string CardNumber { get; set; }
public required string CardName { get; set; }
public required string PersonName { get; set; }
public string? PersonMiddleName { get; set; }
public required string PersonLastName { get; set; }
public DateTime? AccessTime { get; set; }
public int? GC { get; set; }
public int? AccessType { get; set; }
public string? Info { get; set; }
public required string PersonId { get; set; }
```

Query:

```
var totalInsideVisitors = await _context.AccessDatas
     .Where(a => a.AccessType == 2)
     .GroupBy(a => new { a.PersonId, a.AccessType })
     .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(a => a.AccessTime).FirstOrDefault())
     .Where(a => a != null)
     .CountAsync(a => a.GC == 1);
```

Comment: Where is the error? What is the error message?

Comment: Error Message: The given key 'EmptyProjectionMember' was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. What is `GetQuery` for example.

Comment: Hi. GetQuery is IQueryable<AccessData>. I have changed my question to be more understandable.

Comment: What EF Core version are you using? Also try removing `.Where(a => a != null)` line, it has no effect after `GroupBy` (groupings always contain at least one item) and may only cause issues with query translator.

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev Thanks for the answer. As you said, removing the Where query fixed the problem.

Comment: @B_Cbk Thanks for your answer, but when I memorize it with tolist, it may create a performance problem for 1 million records.